# How to inspect an object's property if the property name is an empty string?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Javascript objects' properties can be named with the empty string, for example:

```
foo = { 
    "" : "bar"
}
```

Dot notation does not seem to be able to call this property.  Console output:

```
foo.
>> "missing name after . operator"
```

How would you call the "" property?

Comment: Same way you'd access a property that contains anything else that wouldn't be legal JavaScript syntax.

Comment: "An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty string." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: I'm not sure if that comment is directed at me; a valid JavaScript *string* isn't necessarily valid JavaScript *code*, which is what the dot notation is.

Answer (score 5):

Use an empty string as a key with the bracket syntax:

```
foo[""]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with square bracket notation.  Console output:

```
foo[""]
>> "bar"
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: Anyone know if it's possible with dot notation?

Comment: @meetalexjohnson—no. Dot notation can only be used with property names that are [*valid identifiers*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6) (e.g. something that could be used as a variable name), and "" doesn't fit the criteria.

Comment: @meetalexjohnson Wait, why did you comment on your own answer?

Comment: This actually isn't the only type of object key that can't be expressed with dot notation. `foo["Now this is a story all about how my life got flipped turned upside down"] = bar;` is valid, and you can similarly only access it through square bracket notation.